# curses moving cursor to non blank position

Tags: c, cursor, cygwin, move, curses

I'm writing a simple text editor in C, on cygwin using curses, now I have a screen full of line of text, some line are partial lines, now when I move the cursor up or down one line I want it to move to non blank position if the previous/next line is partial line, how to do it?
any help will be greatly appreciated. thanks.

Comment: What did you try? There are *many* possible ways. A straight-forward idea would be to store the line-lengths together with your text buffer.

Comment: loosely related side note: for windows console applications, you might want to look into [PDCurses](http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/) and compile using this with `mingw`. That way, you'll get an executable independent from the whole `cygwin` runtime.

Comment: actually I thought about it several day and didn't find a solution. searched on the internet and didn't find an answer to it.

Comment: would you mention some of the other ways Felix?. thanks

Comment: you can read the contents of your `WINDOW *` line and find the end dynamically, but that's cumbersome and wasteful. Instead of storing line lengths, you can store a pointer to the end of the line. You have to decide whether your buffer stores *logical lines* (possibly longer than your `WINDOW *` width) or *physical lines*. I'd go with the *logical lines*, a bit more calculation for finding the `x` index of your last character, but much easier to manage otherwise.

Comment: There are probably countless ideas for implementations, but as long as you don't come up with an idea easier than storing line lengths and using them on vertical cursor movement, I'd say it's the most straight-forward thing to do.

Comment: any hints about storing line lengths with the buffer? did you mean embedding the lengths inside the text buffer?

Comment: use for example an array of structs for your individual lines, containing the length and a pointer to the line content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

curses (and ncurses and PDCurses) all support the [`winch`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inch.3x.html) function, which allows an application to read the character stored at the current cursor position.  Likewise, all versions of curses *can* and *do* represent some characters as multiple cells.  So storing line-lengths and attempting to use those as column numbers on the screen can produce unsatisfactory results.

As an example, you could do something like this (for simplicity, all in-line and just for the standard screen `stdscr` — real programs aren't really like this):

```
int y, x, xc;
bool partial = TRUE;
getyx(stdscr, y, x);
if (y > 0) {
    y--;
    for (xc = x; xc < COLS; ++xc) {
        move(y, xc);
        if ((inch() & A_CHARTEXT) != ' ') {
            partial = FALSE;
            break; /* found a nonblank cell at or beyond current x */
        }
    }
    if (partial) {
        for (xc = x; xc >= 0; --xc) {
            move(y, xc);
            if ((inch() & A_CHARTEXT) != ' ') {
                break; /* found the last nonblank cell on the line */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, but what if the last character/characters in the partial line is space/spaces?

Comment: The sample code first checks (starting at the current position) if there are nonblanks -- which leave the X-ordinate unchanged.  If there were no nonblanks, then it scans to the left, and on each test it is moving the current position to the cell which is tested.  If it fails to find nonblanks, that leaves the cursor at the left side of the screen.